Best disk configuration when multibooting
Basic Structure
I have 2 SSDs in my laptop, one 256gb and 512gb. The configuration I want is to keep my data on 512gb and OS(es) on 256gb (multiple distros hopefully). My question is about how to best partition my disks. I don't planning on using Windows with this config, so no problems about that.
Specifically, should I

make a separate / and /home when I'm keeping my data in a separate drive (and symlink the folders).
make different /boot for the distros so it is easy to delete just one later without messing with others.
make a different /swap for each distro or just use one common partition

My planned distros
I am not sure how useful this is while answering, but my plan is to keep one stable distro like Fedora Silverblue, while I distrohop and use stuff like void linux, arch, openSuse as my other distro.
My experience
Again, cannot comment on how relevant this is, but I have been using Linux for the past year or so, and I have some elementary proficiency ie I can troubleshoot a bit and am not completely new to the terminal.
Let me know if any more information is needed.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm not sure what more should I exactly add, as this is what my problem is: what the disk configuration should be. I'll happily supply details if I know what is it that is lacking.

Welcome, there is no "best" configuration, it all depends on how are you going to use the machine. Unless you just want to experiment, I would not recommend any of what you are suggesting. You are going to drown in problems that are not worth the time/effort, for example boot UEFI issues. Different OS have different swap systems (file vs partition for example). This is just my opinion, but if you want to distro hop while maintaining a stable OS, better use VMs, different disks or spare computers.

Maybe will be better to use virtual machines, not multiply installations
